# Start an executable using the file's own parent dir as working dir

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that contains multiple start commands that run different executable files, but rather than using the executable files's parent directory as working dir, they seem to be started under batch file's current working dir.
Is there any way to fix this without manually changing current directory before every start command?
Example:

```
start "" /b "d:\programs\test\test.exe"
```

Should use the start directory d:\programs\test.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
start "" /b /d "d:\programs\test" "d:\programs\test\test.exe"
```

The `/d` parameter specifies the starting directory.

Use `start /?` for more information.